# Running qemu remotely (via ssh)

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, qemu, sshd

I have a server that I am experimenting with, and sometimes I want to work from home so I installed the 'ssh daemon' (namely, 'sshd') and I can ssh to the server. This works fine. But when I try to run a virtual machine on the server with 'qemu', I get the following error `Could not initialize SDL(No available video device) - exiting`.

Is it possible to run qemu via ssh connection?

Note, I do not want to see the visual interface to the VM that I'm launching. I just want to to run.

Answer (score 63):

Try `qemu -curses`
or `qemu -nographic`
to bypass the SDL

Comment: How do you quit from the curses interface?

Comment: @k4rtik In case of `-curses`: Alt-1 opens the qemu monitor, then type "quit" followed by return. In case of `-nographic`: press ctrl-a followed by x to exit (or h for help).

Answer (score 16):

Best way to resolve this is to add `-X` to your ssh parameters.

e.g. `ssh -X user@server`

This will allow the window created by QEMU to be X-Forwarded through SSH to you. It doesn't matter if you want to view the window or not, if QEMU can't open it, it will consider it a fatal error and you will get the error you described.

Comment: This solution is helping me out. I am using ubuntu 16.04 on EC2 of AWS.

Answer (score 9):

You can disable the video card:

```
qemu -vga none (...options...)
```

You could also pipe the screen to VNC instead of SDL - the following will provide a VNC server on port 5901:

```
qemu -vnc :1 (...options...)
```

Comment: `-vnc :1` was the solution for me (no `-curses` nor `-nographic` required). connected later with `vncviewer QEMU_SERVER_IP:5901` (tigervnc)

Answer (score 9):

`qemu-system-i386 -curses` works like charm..

And to exit from that, use `ESC + 2` then `q + ENTER`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.
I think bitwise can't open a new terminal window like qemu does.
You can write  make clean qemu-nox in terminal, instead of just  make clean qemu and it will launch it in the same window. 
This worked for me